# Ubuntu 16. 10 has experienced an internal error

Tags: 14.04, 13.04, xubuntu, lubuntu

I have upgraded my Ubuntu to 16.10 and I am getting such errors. I am not aware of this things. I have searched on for solution and found that I need unity-control-center package but its already installed. So I dont know how to solve this error.

[image: See this Image. I am getting this error.]

Comment: You appear to be affected by [this bug.](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1500750)  I recommend that you subscribe to it and/or it's [called duplicate](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1300713) so that the developers can prioritize their work.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem save for I have 16.04 and my show details only showed the following:

```
/usr/bin/gnome-software
```

What I did to fix it was quite a bit of googling which lead me here https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/404433

Eventually I did

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Haven't seen the problem since then. I hope this helps you out.